# Playing movies with MPMoviePlayer -- controls will not display

Tags: objective-c, cocoa-touch, ios, mpmovieplayercontroller

I want to play a movie with controls -- Play, Stop, Fast Forward, etc. I use this code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    NSURL *movieUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:
                       [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Spot" 
                                                       ofType:@"mp4"]];

    MPMoviePlayerController* myMovie=[[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] 
                                      initWithContentURL:movieUrl];

    //disable scaling of our movie
    myMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeNone;
    [myMovie.view setFrame: myView.bounds];  
    [myView addSubview: myMovie.view];

    [[myMovie view] setFrame:[myView bounds]];
    myMovie.initialPlaybackTime = 2.0;

    [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] addObserver:self 
                                             selector:@selector(movieFinished:) 
                                                 name:MPMoviePlayerPlaybackDidFinishNotification 
                                               object:myMovie]; 
    myMovie.scalingMode = MPMovieScalingModeAspectFill;
    myMovie.controlStyle = MPMovieControlStyleEmbedded;
    [myMovie play];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view from its nib.
}
```

The movie works, but there are no controls. Can anyone help me please?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try if this works ...

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    NSString *urlStr = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"Spot.mp4" ofType:nil];
    NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:urlStr];
    moviePlayer = [[MPMoviePlayerController alloc] initWithContentURL:url];
    [self.view addSubview:moviePlayer.view];
    moviePlayer.view.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, 300, 400);  
    [moviePlayer play];
}
```

You will get all the controls.